# Jersey - validation on a List of Strings

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

The `@Valid` request object for my Jersey 2 REST service has a `List<String>` of ids as a field, which I'm trying to validate against a pattern? I've tried something like the following...

```
public class MyRequestObject {

    @NotNull
    @Pattern( regexp = Patterns.MY_ID_PATTERN )
    private List<String> ids;

}
```

...which is giving me the error when calling the service:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.util.List<java.lang.String>.
```

Will I need to build a custom validator or is there a way to validate against a list of elements?